# Peer to Peer Live Streaming in Java?

Tags: java, video, web, video-streaming, p2p

I was wondering if their was some way to webcam peer to peer in Java. Maybe some sort of library to create a server and stream both webcams to that server on connection? Maybe you could give me some links to Libraries that would do this..(Kind of like Skype).

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) or the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html).  I think either of these can point you in the right direction.